# Serviceclient problem invoking operations which have extended classes as parameters

Tags: class, apache-axis, message, invoke

Serviceclient problem invoking operations which have extended classes as parameters

I have operation input that have exteded class xsd:shema

SOAPFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP11Factory();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = fac.getDefaultEnvelope();
        OMNamespace omNs = fac.createOMNamespace(
                "http://impl.service.mobile.boerse.com/", "impl");
//        // creating the payload
        OMElement method = fac.createOMElement("getIndexData", omNs);
        OMElement value = fac.createOMElement("arg0.deviceType", omNs);
        value.setText("1");
        method.addChild(value);
        OMElement value2 = fac.createOMElement("arg0.identificationID", omNs);
        value2.setText("1");
        method.addChild(value2);
        OMElement value4 = fac.createOMElement("arg0.name", omNs);
        value4.setText("1");
        method.addChild(value4);
        OMElement value3 = fac.createOMElement("arg1", omNs);
        value3.setText("1");
        method.addChild(value3);
        envelope.getBody().addChild(method);

where is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

```
SOAPFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP11Factory();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = fac.getDefaultEnvelope();
OMNamespace omNs = fac.createOMNamespace("http://impl.service.mobile.boerse.com/", "tns");
// // creating the payload
OMElement method = fac.createOMElement("getIndexData", omNs);
OMElement arg0 = fac.createOMElement(new QName("arg0"));
OMElement value = fac.createOMElement(new QName("deviceType"));
value.setText("1");
arg0.addChild(value);
OMElement value2 = fac.createOMElement(new QName("identificationID"));
value2.setText("1");
arg0.addChild(value2);
OMElement value4 = fac.createOMElement(new QName("name"));
value4.setText("1");
arg0.addChild(value4);
OMElement arg1 = fac.createOMElement(new QName("arg1"));
arg1.setText("1");
method.addChild(arg0);
method.addChild(arg1);
envelope.getBody().addChild(method);
return envelope;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have extended class parementer such as operationname.anotherclass.paremeter

at first create anotherclass OMElement after create paremeter OMElement and add paremeter anatherclass